# How to capture image as gray-scale mode using android camerax

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera2

Working on an app using Camera-X and I want to capture images in grayscale mode before saving the image,
I checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138077/how-to-convert-captured-bitmap-to-8-bit-image-as-gray-scale) but no solution, what is the best way to go about this.

Comment: did u find any solution ???